# Change in original array but the clone array stay the same; C#

Tags: c#, arrays, clone

Here is my original array called "gridPlacement"

Original Array: "gridPlacement"

Clone Array: "p1"

```cs
class gridMemory
{
    static public string[] gridPlacement =
        new string[9] {"x", "b", "c", "h", null, null, null, null, null };
}
```

Here is my cloned array called "p1". Although, it is only consist some part of the original array.

```cs
class handleWinLost
{
    static public string[] p1 = new string[3] {
        gridMemory.gridPlacement[0],
        gridMemory.gridPlacement[3]
        gridMemory.gridPlacement[2]
    };
}
```

When I made changes to the index 2 of original array from "c" to "b". Array `p1` last element stay the same, "c". Even though, `gridMemory.gridPlacement[2]` which is `p1[2]`.

Comment: As an aside, I strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions, and please take more care over making your posts readable in the future - refer to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reflect changes of the original array, store indexes instead:

```cs
public static int[] p1 = new int[3] { 0, 3, 2 };
```

And then get the values like this:

```cs
string value = gridMemory.gridPlacement[p1[i]];
```

---

You can also make `p1` private and provide a method for the access:

```cs
private static int[] p1 = new int[3] { 0, 3, 2 };

public static int PlacementCount => p1.Length;

public static string GetPlacementAt(int index) 
{
    return gridMemory.gridPlacement[p1[index]];
}
```

and access it like this (in a loop as an example):

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < handleWinLost.PlacementCount; i++) {
    string placement = handleWinLost.GetPlacementAt(i);
    Console.WriteLine(placement);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!  Why didn't i come up with that solution before giving up and turn to stackOverflow

Answer (score 3):

This statement:

```cs
static public string[] p1 = new string[3] {
    gridMemory.gridPlacement[0],
    gridMemory.gridPlacement[3]
    gridMemory.gridPlacement[2]
};
```

... creates an array, and assigns values to the element. Leaving aside the fact that it's a field declaration, it's equivalent to:

```cs
string[] p1 = new string[3];
p1[0] = gridMemory.gridPlacement[0];
p1[1] = gridMemory.gridPlacement[3];
p1[2] = gridMemory.gridPlacement[2];
```

Each of those assignments just evaluates the expression on the right hand side, and copies it to the array element described on the left hand side. It *doesn't* set up any lasting relationship between say `p1[0]` and `gridMemory.gridPlacement[0]`. Any later changes in `gridMemory.gridPlacement` are completely irrelevant to `handleWinLost.p1`.

Comment: I expected you to show how to do this using `ref`

Comment: @Hogan: Even if that were feasible (and I'm not at all sure it is, although I know this is an area that's been changing), if the OP doesn't understand how their existing code works, I really wouldn't want to confuse them with more advanced `ref` functionality.

Comment: You're right, of course.  Mostly **I** was interested in how to marshal the reference in unsafe code to make it work.  Of course, that his not the best answer by a long shot.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! @JonSkeet. I didn't though of that way since arrays are reference type so i thought there was a relationship between them that ultimately in the end refer to the same address.

Comment: @Satchua: But you're explicitly creating two separate array objects. If your code had been `static public string[] p1 = gridMemory.gridPlacement;` that would be a different matter - then you'd have two variables (`p1` and `gridPlacement`) which have values referring to the same array object.

Answer (score 2):

You intend to run this line of code:

```
gridMemory.gridPlacement[2] = "b";
```

Ultimately, strings are reference types with some special treatment to give them value semantics. This means initially you have two reference variables — `gridMemory.gridPlacement[2]` and `p1[2]` — that both refer to the same string object in memory, which happens to have a value of `"c"`.

That is, we have the variable `gridMemory.gridPlacement[2]`, whose value is a *reference* to some address in memory, and we have the variable `p1[2]` whose value is a different reference to the same address in memory. This is because the reference in `gridMemory.gridPlacement[2]` was assigned to `p1[2]`. However, this assignment *copies the reference* so you now have two references. They happen to target the same memory, but *they are not the same reference*.

So now we run the line of code. What it does is create a new string object in memory (`"b"`), and assign a reference to that string object to `gridMemory.gridPlacement[2]`.

At no point is `p1[2]` ever involved in this line of code. `p1[2]` has its own reference. This reference still refers to the same memory, which still has a value of `"c"`.